# ImageMagick / Colorspace 'safe' images

Tags: imagemagick, rgb, image-manipulation

Converting all images to RGB is quite handful to make sure all uploaded images are displayed in this specific color format.

Using it through imagemagick, the following :

```
-colorspace RGB
```

seems to be the option to pass.

However, the images processed with this option are quite darkened, which is a problem.
Is there another option to pass to make sure the conversion preserve the colors used ?

Comment: Do you mean that images displayed om the web are dark? If so, you probably actually want to use `-colorspace sRGB` since that is the colourspace of the web.

Comment: should you add this as an answer for me to vote it up ?

Comment: If it worked for you that will be great - and it will end my week on a very satisfactory 16k points! Thank you!

Comment: It did yep; Huge score man !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want to use `-colorspace sRGB` since that is actually the colourspace of the Web, if there is such a thing.